# Scikit-learn FunctionTransformer error: dataframe has no attribute str / invalid shape

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want a nice and neat pipeline and columntransformer that handles ALL of my data preprocessing at once. I seem to be unable to translate my column cleaning functions into a functiontransformer that works without giving errors.

```
def clean_bathrooms(bathrooms_text):
    #cleans the bathrooms... har har har... no actually it cleans the bathrooms_text column

    bathrooms_text = bathrooms_text.copy()
    pattern = r'(\d.?\d?)\s'
    pattern2 = r'(Half)'
    bathrooms_text.loc[bathrooms_text.str.contains(pattern2, na=False)] = .5
    bathrooms_text = bathrooms_text.str.extract(pattern)
    return bathrooms_text.astype(float)


def clean_property_type(property_type_col):
    #consolidate the property_type var to a few common categories 
     
    property_type_col = property_type_col.copy()
    property_type_col.loc[property_type_col.str.contains(r'Entire')] = 'Entire Unit'
    property_type_col.loc[property_type_col.str.contains(r'Tiny home')] = 'Entire Unit'
    property_type_col.loc[property_type_col.str.contains(r'[Rr]oom')] = 'Single Room'
    property_type_col.loc[property_type_col.str.contains(r'Camp')] = 'Camping'

    property_type_col.loc[~property_type_col.isin(['Camping', 'Single Room', 'Entire Unit'])] = np.nan
    return property_type_col
```

Both of these functions are causing issues.
Here are the pipelines:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector

num_pipe = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'),
    StandardScaler()
)

cat_pipe = make_pipeline(   # host_is_superhost
    SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),
    OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary')
)

bathrooms_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(func=clean_bathrooms),
    SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'),
    StandardScaler()
)

property_type_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(func=clean_property_type),
    SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
)

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
    ('clean_bathrooms', bathrooms_pipeline, ['bathrooms_text']),
    ('clean_property_type', property_type_pipeline, ['property_type']),
    ('cat', cat_pipe, make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
],
remainder=num_pipe)
```

When I call either bathrooms_pipeline.fit_transform or property_type_pipeline.fit_transform on the individual respective columns, it gives me the error 'dataframe has no attribute str'.

I have tried forcing it to convert the columns to series via .squeeze() but then it gives me the error that the data is the wrong shape. I have tried then returning the columns as a dataframe, but it then ALSO gives me an error about the data being the wrong shape. Are my inputs and outputs wrong? The functions take in a column, and return a column.

Is what I am trying to do too advanced for a sklearn pipeline? I have been unable to find ANYTHING online about someone trying to do this with a dataframe.Typically functiontrasnformers just use np.log or something simple like that, or a short lambda function.

Thank you for your help. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Added:
Something I am doing is just fundamentally wrong and I have no idea what it is.

I've tried doing a different piece here using entirely different function logic:

```
t = df[['price']].copy()

# Define the extract_price function
def extract_price(price_series):
    # Converts price column to floats
    return price_series.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('$','').replace(',','')) if isinstance(x, str) else x)

# Create a FunctionTransformer
clean_price = FunctionTransformer(func=extract_price)

# Define the pipeline
clean_price_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    clean_price,
    SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'),
    FunctionTransformer(np.log1p),
    StandardScaler()
)

clean_price_pipeline.fit_transform(t)
```

I've tried using a lambda function instead but to no avail. I am getting the error "ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: '$100.00'".

What am I doing wrong? Why can none of my functions work as a functiontransformer?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The functions are receiving a dataframe rather than a series, as you are supplying column names as a `list`. Try replacing `['property_type']` with just `'property_type'`.

Alternatively, inside the actual function, you could read the column out as a series and return the result as a dataframe:

```
def clean_property_type(property_type_col):
    #Convert the single df column to series
    property_type_col = property_type_col.iloc[:, 0].copy()

    #modify the data...

    return property_type_col.to_frame()  #convert back to dataframe
```